# event.target.id Only working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

The wierdest thing.

I have a function which calls:

```
var clicked_el = event.target.id;
```

This function breaks at this line in FireFox. It works in ie9, but not in 8 (because ie8 uses srcElement instead). Every attempt to grab the id of the element which initiated the event has been a complete flameout on my end.

I think there is a way that jQuery smoothes out browser incosistencies with `jQuery.Event` but I can't get anything working.

Can anyone tell me a better browser consistent method to do this?

here is the function, it's part of my backbone view.

```
  open: function () {
    iconState = true;
    var self = this;
    var clicked_el = event.target.id;
        $('div.hr, div#footer_icons').animate({
            top : '-=300'
        }, 500, function () {
            if (innerContentIsVisible === false) {
                $('#a_close').fadeIn(500);
            }
        });
        $('div#article').animate({
            opacity : 0
        }, 500,function () {
            self.load_content(clicked_el);
        });
  },
```

**UPDATE**

The `open` function was being called from another function, and I forgot to pass the event paramater when I invoked the `open` function, which is why it was returning `undefined`.

here is the function which now passes the `event` param:

```
click: function(event) {
    if (iconState === false) {
        this.open(event);
    } else {
        var self = this;
        var clicked_el_icon = event.target.id;
        $('div#loaded_content').fadeOut(250, function() {
            self.load_content(clicked_el_icon);
        });
    }
      },

open: function (event) {
  iconState = true;
  alert(event);
  var self = this;
  var clicked_el = event.target.id;
    $('div.hr, div#footer_icons').animate({
        top : '-=300'
    }, 500, function () {
        if (innerContentIsVisible === false) {
            $('#a_close').fadeIn(500);
        }
    });
    $('div#article').animate({
        opacity : 0
    }, 500,function () {
        self.load_content(clicked_el);
    });
    },
```

Thanks... I will not forget this lesson.

Comment: Where is `event` defined? Normally, it should be in `open: function(event){` I would've thought, unless it's been defined someplace else beforehand?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yea, that seems to be the problem. firefox gives me an `event is not defined` error. This function is evoked after an element in a sidebar is clicked, I need to get the ID of the element that was clicked, so that I can pass it to load_content and load the appropriate content. I have not defined `event` previously, should I wrap this in jquery? like `var clicked_el = $(this).event.target('id');` That's not real, so take it as pseudocode :)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just put event into the parenthesis as shown in my first comment? Why complicate things?

Comment: Hah, about the complicating things- I guess it comes with not really knowing what you're doing. I added `event` as the parameter for `open`, but it breaks in chrome and firefox... I tried changing event to `evt` with `evt` as the paramater for `open` as well to no avail.

Comment: So, you might want to post a minimal demo that reproduces your problem to something like [JS Fiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/), so's we can see what's going on.

Comment: So I'm confused, @Lsdafjklsd - does it work or does it "break in Chrome and Firefox"?  You accepted my answer so that makes me think it works to add "event" as a parameter, but I'm confused now by your comment above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare "event" as the parameter for the "open" handler function.

Comment: Ha ha sorry dude; type in an answer if you like and I'll upvote it :-)

Comment: There's no need for that, really; the goal is to answer and to help, not the rep =)

Comment: Well it looks like my answer might be wrong anyway!  Maybe that "open" thing doesn't actually get passed the event object by the Backbone framework.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't. It needed to be passed along through the `click` function which backbone did pass the event object initially. Thanks again guys.